# How to filter the widgets like calendar and archives based on category in WordPress

Tags: widgets

Thanks for the reply now the news page and blog page of my website has sidebars to specific to those, but now the new problem raised on the widgets side. Specifically Calendar and Archive widget are mixing. news posted and blog posted dates are getting mixed up.Please suggest me how to filter these based on category. Please help me with the plugin if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Filters widgets you can use to cahnge the output of the calendar and archive

Calendar

- get_calendar

For archive widget you need to use a filters for parts of sql (changing sql statments)

- getarchives_join
- getarchives_where